# Alternating row colors in a ForEach loop

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor, foreach, foreach-loop-container

**My foreach code**

Notice that my second row has a different background color.

```
@foreach (var item in Model.fNameList)
{
    <tr>
        <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick='call();' style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00001</a></td>
        <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:200px;"> @item.firstName</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td style ="background-color:#fff; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick="call();" style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00001</a></td>
        <td style ="background-color:#fff; height:40px;width:200px;"> @item.firstName</td>
    </tr>
}
```

I want my second *TR* tag to have the second value of my "FIRSTNAME", example: if *var item[0]* is **"FIRSTNAME" = "GEM"**, and *var item[1]* is **"FIRSTNAME" = "DIAMOND"**. now if I run my code, the value of my first *TR* tag has **"FIRSTNAME" = "GEM"** while in the second *TR* tag the value is **"FIRSTNAME" = "GEM"** as well. Now I want my second *TR* tag to have the value: **"FIRSTNAME" = "DIAMOND"**.

Comment: I'm sorry, My question was wrong. I was planing to have two TR tags with different background color. But when I run this code the my excepted output for the background color works, but the value of my FIRSTNAME was duplicated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**EDIT**
Ok, I understand your issue more now, you are wanting to do alternating row colors.  The best way to do that is to set a variable that allows you to know if you are alternating or not.  I have updated my example to show this.

Then, you only need one set of `<tr>` in your foreach loop then.  Each item will output exactly one `<tr>`.

```
@{
    var altRow = false;
    foreach (var item in Model.fNameList)
    {
        <tr>
            <td style ="background-color:@(altRow ? "#fff" : "#E0EBEB"); height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick='call();' style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00001</a></td>
            <td style ="background-color:@(altRow ? "#fff" : "#E0EBEB"); height:40px;width:200px;"> @item.firstName</td>
        </tr>
        altRow = !altRow; 
    }
}
```

What this does is switches the altRow variable from true to false on each iteration through the foreach loop.  When true, it will set the background color to #fff and when false, #E0EBEB

So - if we walk through this code with the following data:

```
item[0].FirstName = "Gem"
item[1].FirstName = "Diamond"
```

Then the expected output will be

```
    <tr>
        <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick='call();' style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00001</a></td>
        <td style ="background-color:#E0EBEB; height:40px;width:200px;">Gem</td>
    </tr> 
    <tr>
        <td style ="background-color:#fff; height:40px;width:100px;"><a href ="#" onclick='call();' style ="text-decoration:none; text-decoration-color:black;"> T-00001</a></td>
        <td style ="background-color:#fff; height:40px;width:200px;">Diamond</td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: but in the first TR the style = "background-color:#E0EBEB;", while in the second TR the style = "background-color:#fff;". if I only use one TR tag both GEM and DIAMOND has same background color.

Comment: I now see your problem.  Please check my edit for addtional information

Comment: Parser Error in line: @foreach (var item in Model.fNameList) Parser Error Message: Unexpected "foreach" keyword after "@" character.  Once inside code, you do not need to prefix constructs like "foreach" with "@". When I try to delete the @ from the foreach it runs but the row didn't alternate.

Comment: It work... Thanks, but the altRow = !altRow; must be inside the foreach after the /tr tag and the foreach must not have an @ symbol

Comment: @SeeYahLater - good call on both accounts, I was a little rushed in my response.  I have updated accordingly.  I am glad I was able to get you on the right path.